# HDD for Videos storage

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage

I would like to know the best HDD for massive videos storage, and by massive I mean: at least 2-3GB per each video.

I've tried HGST 8TB HDD but is not working for me because the enclosure I got is not giving enough power to run correctly or maybe is my laptop's fault.

So, I was thinking about smallest HDDs like 2TB/each.

What should I pick to store videos and don't worry about losing any data in the next 3-4 years?

According to Backblaze's tests, HGST and Toshiba seem to be the best if we talk about failure rate.

So yeah, I would need like 5-10HDDs at 2TB each HDD, that's like 10TB or 20TB of videos.

What do you guys recommend? Thanks

Comment: I recommend two hard drives, so that when one fails, you can read the data off the other one.

Comment: ^^^^ @Mark is describing a RAID setup.

Comment: I'd recommend a NAS or external RAID controller with server-grade or NAS-grade HDDs. Personally, I use WD Red drives, and when you look for drives, look for something designed to be running constantly.

Comment: I agree with NoahL, a Network Attached Server would be a great way to store your videos. I have a 3tb NAS server running in my college dorms and I can stream 1080p movies off it through my campus' router array. There are plently of ready to deploy NAS servers you can buy, or [you could try setting up a network share yourself](http://www.freenas.org/)

Comment: How much does cost matter?  A samsung 2tb 850 ssd is $700, but is way more reliable than any hdd.  They have no moving parts to fail.